# Weird line trough diamond shape with opencv approxPolyDP

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to detect shapes with OpenCV and Python. For some reason, the ApproxPolyDP-function adds a weird line trough the diamond-shaped object (see attached image). I've tried some googling, but I'm very new to opencv and computer vision, so I could not find anything useful. This is my code:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("test.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img_Base = cv2.imread("test.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

contours, _ = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

for contour in contours:
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour, 0.1*cv2.arcLength(contour, True), True)
    cv2.drawContours(img_Base, [approx], 0, (255, 0, 255), 2)

cv2.imshow('image', img_Base)
cv2.waitKey()
```

I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what.

[The weird line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvWgB.png)

Comment: You should threshold your input image so that your objects are white. Then use cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL contours to get only the external contour rather than all the contours from RET_TREE

Comment: threshold, or invert. inverting is just `inverted = 255 - img`. OpenCV definitely expects objects to be white and background to be black.

Comment: Thanks, altough the problem still remains even after thresholding and using the external contour function.

Comment: I found the problem: it has something to do with the approxpolydp function, because if I draw the regular contours, it shows the outside of the diamond.